# How to resolve Bower dependency version conflicts?

Tags: bower

I have a project that depends on both:

- jquery ~1.9.1
- another project which in turn depends on jquery >=1.7.2

But when I run `bower install`, it ends up installing jquery 2.0.2.
This seems broken.

How do I either (a) make it correctly solve the constraints or (b) explicitly force a final version to be installed (workaround)?

Comment: Ticket: https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/540

Comment: you would have 2 projects here - so one would get one version of jQ and the other a different version so I am thinking you need more detail in your question.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem, as I am having the exact same thing and neilhem's solution doesn't work for me (as in, it didn't make any difference)?

Comment: my work around is run `bower install jQuery#2.1.4 --save`

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You can add `resolutions` to the object in your `bower.json` file and specify the component name & version to automatically resolve the conflict when running bower commands.
Like this:

```
{
  "name": "project-x",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "~3.3.7",
    "modernizr": "~2.8.3",
    "jquery": "~1.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery": "~1.11.3"
  }
}
```

Also you can run `bower install` and when bower will ask for "suitable version" (if interactive mode is on), prefix choice with `!`, so bower will save your choice into bower.json file.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. It doesn't seem to make a difference. Does it require a certain version of Bower and mine happens to be too old (it's installed from npm, so whatever that version is).

Comment: @Hans try to update bower running: npm update -g bower

Comment: Great answer.  This should be marked as correct.  Putting ! in front of the choice was extra helpful.

Comment: To add to @neilhem answer: bower install will not ask "suitable version" if interactive mode is off. [more information](http://bower.io/docs/api/#non-interactive-mode)

Comment: Anything like this for npm (package.json)?

Comment: @AlonAmir npm uses nested dependency tree. More here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641899/what-is-the-difference-between-bower-and-npm

Comment: You can also save your resolution typing the chose number + !, eg: 2!

Answer (score 0):

use `--force-latest`

[enter link description here](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/1265)