# Resolution Bower versions conflict

Tags: bower

Situation I have is described here: [How to resolve Bower dependency version conflicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991128/how-to-resolve-bower-dependency-version-conflicts)

The problem is that proposed solution does not work. Adding a `resolution` section to `bower.json` does nothing and it still requires to choose package version manually on each installation.

But, surprisingly, when I install bower packages though Grunt (with [grunt-bower-task](https://github.com/yatskevich/grunt-bower-task)), it just works, even without `resolutions`.

I have the latest bower version (1.4.1 for now).

Does anybody know what's going on and is it possible to make bower to install without manual resolution?

Comment: Can you provide your `bower.json` file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use "--save" or "--save-dev" when you install and resolve these conflicts - in this way, bower will update accordingly the json file. Next time when you run bower install, bower will read the written sections and will not ask you any more.

No need for manual edits - unless you know what you're doing.