# Bower: multi versions of angular seem to run on my project

Tags: angular, build, bower

At the end of `bower update` command. I found this warning:

```
Please note that,
     angular-bootstrap#2.5.0 depends on angular#>=1.4.0 which resolved to angular#1.5.11
     angularytics#0.4.0 depends on angular#* which resolved to angular#1.5.11
     angular-gettext#2.3.8 depends on angular#>=1.2.0 which resolved to angular#1.5.11
     angular-pnotify#0.1.2 depends on angular#~1.5.5 which resolved to angular#1.5.11
     angular-local-storage#0.5.2 depends on angular#^1.x which resolved to angular#1.5.11
     angular-marked#1.2.2 depends on angular#>= 1.3.0 which resolved to angular#1.5.11
     ng-videosharing-embed#0.3.7 depends on angular#>= 1.2.0 which resolved to angular#1.5.11
     ngSmoothScroll#2.0.0 depends on angular#^1.2.0 which resolved to angular#1.5.11
     ng-file-upload#12.2.13 depends on angular#>1.2.0 which resolved to angular#1.5.11
     ng-sortable#1.3.7 depends on angular#>=1.3.0 which resolved to angular#1.5.11
     textAngular#1.5.16 depends on angular#>=1.3.x which resolved to angular#1.5.11
     angular-animate#1.6.1, angular-cookies#1.6.1, angular-resource#1.6.1, angular-route#1.6.1, angular-sanitize#1.6.1, angular-touch#1.6.1 depends on angular#1.6.1 which resolved to angular#1.6.1                                               
     the-web-project depends on angular#~1.6.1 which resolved to angular#1.6.1
 Resort to using angular#~1.6.1 which resolved to angular#1.6.1
 Code incompatibilities may occur.
```

I'm concluding, that there are two versions of angular running on my app. Is this true? Is there an easy way to solve this?

**edit**

I'm adding my `bower.json` because it is already contains a `resolutions` section which specify `angular` version.

```
{
  "name": "my-web-project",
  "version": "2.3.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "~3.1.1",
    "angular": "~1.6.1",
    "angular-animate": "~1.6.1",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~2.5.0",
    "angular-bootstrap-colorpicker": "~3.0.25",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.6.1",
    "angular-gettext": "~2.3.8",
    "angular-local-storage": "~0.5.2",
    "angular-marked": "~1.2.2",
    "angular-pnotify": "~0.1.2",
    "angular-resource": "~1.6.1",
    "angular-route": "~1.6.1",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.6.1",
    "angularytics": "~0.4.0",
    "base64-angular": "~1.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.7",
    "es5-shim": "~4.5.9",
    "jquery-ui": "~1.12.1",
    "json3": "~3.3.2",
    "marked": "~0.3.6",
    "md5-jkmyers": "~0.0.1",
    "moment": "~2.17.1",
    "momentjs": "~2.17.1",
    "ng-file-upload": "~12.2.13",
    "ng-sortable": "~1.3.7",
    "ngSmoothScroll": "~2.0.0",
    "textAngular": "~1.5.16",
    "underscore": "~1.8.3",
    "underscore.string": "~3.3.4",
    "angular-touch": "~1.6.1",
    "ng-videosharing-embed": "~0.3.7",
    "ua-parser-js": "~0.7.12",
    "angular-spinners": "~3.1.2",
    "angular-i18n": "^1.6.1",
    "angular.uuid2": "angular-uuid2#*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "~1.6.1",
    "jquery": "~3.1.1"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "main": [
        "less/bootstrap.less",
        "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ]
    },
    "pnotify": {
      "main": [
        "dist/pnotify.js",
        "dist/pnotify.css",
        "dist/pnotify.buttons.css",
        "dist/pnotify.buttons.js"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve Bower dependency version conflicts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991128/how-to-resolve-bower-dependency-version-conflicts)

Comment: The answer is on same register. But the approach between my question and [How to resolve Bower dependency version conflicts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991128/how-to-resolve-bower-dependency-version-conflicts) is quite different. The other question concerns 2 projects. My is concerning only one. Then conclusion are slightly different. Then a remark as *« Usually, it is not a problem, if only one or two dependencies require an older version of angular. »* is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Every bower component has its own dependencies. This may be in a range of versions or a fixed static version. If the several components require angular in different versions (not overlapping version range), this warning occurs. You can then decide, which version should be included, by defining a `resolution` of e.g. angular and set a fixed version. This may lead to incompatibilities when it is running, but at the end, there is only one version running in your project. Usually, it is not a problem, if only one or two dependencies require an older version of angular.

Here is an answer of another question, which explains the definition of resolutions: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24281191/3233827).

Comment: my `bower.json` already contains `"resolutions": {
    "angular": "~1.6.1",
    "jquery": "~3.1.1"
  },`