# Bower install AngularJS failing

Tags: angularjs, bower-install

We use bower in our project to download front end related scripts. The project is hosted on Heroku. `bower install` is part of the build script. Everything was working fine until yesterday. Suddenly, bower is unable to install AngularJS.

Here's my bower.json

```
{
  "name": "laravel.app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "3.2.0",
    "angular": "1.6.4",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.4.2",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.6.4",
    "angular-route": "1.6.4",
    "angular-toastr": "^2.1.1",
    "components-font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "angular-google-picker": "^0.2.2",
    "foundation-datepicker": "^1.5.6",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.0",
    "ng-lodash": "^0.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.18.1"
  }
}
```

The error while building is

`bower angular#~1.4                       cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.14
bower angular#~1.4                     validate 1.4.14 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.4
bower                                 ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular`

This is breaking the build of new commits in Heroku as well. Why could this be happening? All was fine until yesterday.

The core of the error is this

```
ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular
```

Comment: You can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991128/how-to-resolve-bower-dependency-version-conflicts

Comment: Thank you, but why the down vote ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify dependencies for you app via Bower, some of the packages might rely on different versions of the same library.

```
bower install angular#latest --save -F
```

Comment: It was ng-lodash. It was dependent on an older version of angular. Once I ran the command you gave, bower added a field `"angular": "^1.6.6"`  in resolutions node of bower.json. Things are fine now.